# HDF5: compound data type to write a struct containing a pointer to another struct

Tags: c, hdf5

I'm trying to write to HDF5 a struct that contains a pointer to another. Something like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int32_t  method;
    void*    methodParams;
    float    result;
}Measure;

typedef struct{
    int32_t    param1;
    int32_t    param2;
}OneMethod;
```

The following code to describe the compound data type does not work:

```
Measure value;
hid_t method_tid;
hid_t measure_tid;

method_tid = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(OneMethod));
H5Tinsert(method_tid, "P1", HOFFSET(OneMethod, param1), H5T_NATIVE_INT32);
H5Tinsert(method_tid, "P2", HOFFSET(OneMethod, param2), H5T_NATIVE_INT32);

measure_tid = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof(Measure));
H5Tinsert(measure_tid, "Method", HOFFSET(Measure, method), H5T_NATIVE_INT32);
H5Tinsert(measure_tid, "Params", HOFFSET(Measure, methodParams), method_tid);
H5Tinsert(measure_tid, "Result", HOFFSET(Measure, result), H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT);

hsize_t dim[] = { 1 };
hid_t space = H5Screate_simple(1, dim, NULL);

hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate(objid, name, measure_tid, space, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
herr_t ret = H5Dwrite(dataset, measure_tid, H5S_ALL, H5S_ALL, H5P_DEFAULT, &value);

H5Tclose(method_tid);
H5Tclose(measure_tid);
H5Sclose(space);
H5Dclose(dataset);
```

the compound datatype is written but the `methodParams` field is missing. I guess because I'm not instructing the library to expect a pointer at its position. How shall I do it?

**EDIT**

Please consider that the struct is with the pointer because each method (given by the first struct's field) has different *amounts* and *kinds* of parameters. Of course a way would be to merge all the params from all the methods on the first level of the struct, which is something I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

The H5Tinsert() calls are just laying out the bytes for storage and what is actually in that struct is a pointer, not the thing pointed to. Padding aside, the memory you are sending the library consists of an int, a pointer, and a float. The library will simply try to slice and dice that memory according to what you told it about the type arrangement in the H5Tinsert() calls. It will not resolve pointers in complex data structures (people often get confused about this when they try to send multidimensional arrays built with pointers to HDF5).

The most straightforward thing to do would be to revise your structs to look something like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int32_t  method;
    int32_t  param1;
    int32_t  param2;
    float    result;
}hdf5_Measure;
```

And manually fill that, at least for HDF5 I/O.

Comment: thanks I understand that, but this is something I already considered and I would like to avoid. Please see my edits. Any other idea?

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do what you want to do.

Comment: The HDF5 library I/O calls consume and emit buffers of data with minimal transformation. Basically just type conversion and (compression) filters. They do not chase pointers or flatten complicated data structures for you. Packing and unpacking data is up to the client.

Comment: Keep in mind that HDF5 was designed to excel at storing arrays of identically-typed data, like what you find in imaging, physics simulations, etc. It is probably not going to do well at storing data with your level of heterogeneity. HDF5 datasets really aren't designed for that sort of thing.

Comment: If what you are doing in that code is auxiliary to some other HDF5 data, you might investigate storing that struct data as HDF5 attributes (check out the H5A API calls) which you could attach to the dataset(s), group(s), etc. You might also consider using some other storage scheme for your struct data. You could emit those data as JSON, for example. If you need to keep orthogonal storage with an HDF5 file, you could look at the h5jam/h5unjam tools. Those let you prepend files to HDF5 files to create hybrid files.

Comment: Thanks Dana, I find your latest comment very useful